# How to store data in php file itself?

Tags: php

I am making a system which would ask user for mysql details. I want those details to be written in a settings.php file.

Settings file contains the following data:

```
$host = "";
$database = "";
$user = "";
$password = "";
$localelang = "";
```

Comment: What EXACTLY is your question?

Comment: What have you tried?  Seems ambitious to put together a system that would collect such data in a secure way if you are not even familiar yet with how to write files in the file system.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Writing Database Information To A PHP File?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739118/php-writing-database-information-to-a-php-file)

Comment: and possibly a [hundred similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+php%20write%20configuration%20file%20with%20database%20settings)...

Comment: @MikeBrant Let's hope it's for a school project.

Answer (score 1):

View file system operations at http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php - specifically `file_put_contents()` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: After user entered data required to connect to the database i want those details to be stored in settings.php file i mentioned above so that system could use that data later. How do I write that data i got to the specific strings in settings.php?

Answer (score 1):

Save your file as `.ini` instead of `.php` and just use [parse_ini_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) function on it.

Comment: and, for god's sake, protect your ini file via .htaccess (or server-wide config)

Comment: Yes, or put it outside of document_root.

Answer (score 1):

PHP files are text files so you can modify them as you see fit. Here's an easy example:

Your file to modify (file.original.php):

```
$host = "[%%HOST%%]";
$database = "[%%DATABASE%%]";
$user = "[%%USER%%]";
$password = "[%%PASSWORD%%]";
$localelang = "[%%LANG%%]";
```

Modifying script:

```
$file = file_get_contents("path/to/your/file.original.php");

$file = str_replace("[%%HOST%%]", $hostSuppliedByUser, $file);
$file = str_replace("[%%DATABASE%%]", $databaseSuppliedByUser, $file);
```

(and so on for each var)

write to file like this:

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/your/newfile.php', $file);
```

Like Tim suggested, make sure you write to a different file

Comment: Just make sure you save the file under a different name than the one you read, or the second time you modify the file, `"[%%HOST%%]"` will no longer exist, because you overwrote it.

Comment: good point. Edited my answer